# How to not initiate downloading under certain circumstances with the downloadHandler

Tags: r, shiny

I'm wondering how to not initiate downloading but return some warning message within downloadHandler.

I'm trying to work with downloadHandler in shiny. Right now, what my shiny does is that users are able to input a list of datasets to be displayed, and selected certain rows to be viewed across different datasets.
I'm adding a feature to download only the selected rows from all datasets to different sheets of one excel file. The issue I met is that when no data is selected, it still downloads an empty excel file, whereas I want to return a message and not initiate downloading.
Here is my code. I want to only start downloading if `filtered_datasets` is not empty.

```
filtered_datasets = reactiveValues()

####
# manipulate filtered_datasets part
####

output$download <- downloadHandler(
  filename = function() {
    paste("filtered-data-", Sys.Date(), ".xlsx", sep = "")
  },
  content = function(file) {

    # I added this part to check if there's data selected
    if (length(filtered_datasets) == 0 || all(sapply(filtered_datasets, nrow) == 0)) {
      # Stop and return a message to the user
      showModal(modalDialog(
        title = "No Data to Download",
        "Please select some data before attempting to download.",
        easyClose = TRUE,
        footer = NULL
      ))
      return(NULL)  # Exit the download handler
    }
    


    # Proceed with creating the workbook if there is data
    wb <- createWorkbook()
    
    # Add each filtered dataset to a new sheet in the workbook
    for (dataset_name in names(filtered_datasets)) {
      if (nrow(filtered_datasets[[dataset_name]]) > 0) {
        addWorksheet(wb, dataset_name)
        writeData(wb, sheet = dataset_name, filtered_datasets[[dataset_name]])
      }
    }
    
    # Save the workbook to a temporary file
    saveWorkbook(wb, file, overwrite = TRUE)
  }
)
```

Without the if statement I added, the download works just fine, and there's no warning. However, with the if statement, there's indeed a message shown. But it still initiates downloading an excel file called 'download'. And there will be a warning shown whenever I hit download, which will not be shown without the if statement.

```
`as.list.reactivevalues()` is deprecated as of shiny 0.4.0.
Please use `reactiveValuesToList()` instead.
Please see ?reactiveValuesToList for more information.
```

Please let me know if I'm not explaining myself well. Thank you!

Comment: I think you want to keep the validation outside of the downloadhandler. One way is to use an `observe()` containing your condition and {shinyjs} so that the download button is only clickable when the condition is met - would that work for you?

Comment: @smartse That solution would not allow the modal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way.

It hides the `downloadButton` and includes an `actionButton` to trigger the download or not. When this button is clicked, your condition is checked, then:

- a modal is shown if the condition is not fulfilled;
- if the condition is fulfilled, one simulates a click on the true download button using `shinyjs::runjs`.

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  actionButton("btn", "Download", icon = icon("download")),
  downloadButton("dwnld", style = "visibility: hidden;")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  observeEvent(input$btn, {
    if(YOUR-CONDITION-GOES-HERE) {
      runjs("$('#dwnld')[0].click();")
    } else {
      showModal(modalDialog(
        title = "No Data to Download",
        "Please select some data before attempting to download.",
        easyClose = TRUE,
        footer = NULL
      ))
    }
  })
  
  output$dwnld <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste("filtered-data-", Sys.Date(), ".xlsx", sep = "")
    },
    content = function(file) {
      # Proceed with creating the workbook if there is data
      wb <- createWorkbook()
      # Add each filtered dataset to a new sheet in the workbook
      for (dataset_name in names(filtered_datasets)) {
        if (nrow(filtered_datasets[[dataset_name]]) > 0) {
          addWorksheet(wb, dataset_name)
          writeData(wb, sheet = dataset_name, filtered_datasets[[dataset_name]])
        }
      }
      # Save the workbook to a temporary file
      saveWorkbook(wb, file, overwrite = TRUE)
    }
  )
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think using `shinyjs` for disabling the download button makes the most sense here. I'll also switch from a `reactiveValues()` to a single `reactiveVal()`, where it will contain your list of frames. (I could not get this to work with `reactiveValues`, so you'd need to adjust your method of working with this reactive data just a little.

```
library(shiny)
library(shiny)
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
    checkboxInput("cbox", "Put data in the reactiveValues object", value = FALSE),
    downloadButton("down", "Download the data")
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    filtered_datasets <- reactiveVal()
    observeEvent(input$cbox, {
      filtered_datasets( if (input$cbox) list(mtcars) else NULL )
    })
    observeEvent(filtered_datasets(), {
      cond <- Filter(Negate(is.null), filtered_datasets())
      shinyjs::toggleState("down", cond = isTRUE(length(cond) > 0))
    }, ignoreNULL = FALSE)
    output$down <- downloadHandler(
      filename = function() "mtcars.csv",
      content = function(file) {
        req(any(sapply(filtered_datasets(), NROW) > 0))
        write.csv(mtcars, file)
      }
    )
  }
)
```

[image: screenshot of a web browser with a checkbox not selected and a download button disabled]

[image: screenshot of the same web browser, with the checkbox selected, and the download button is enabled and clickable]

I'm using the checkbox as the way to "add data to the list of frames". The relevant portions of this shiny app for you is the `observeEvent` containing `toggleState`.